# How to set a random matrix in this case?

Tags: c, random, boundary

Recently I saw link on this site

[Sweeping through a 2d arrays using pointers with boundary conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494771/sweeping-through-a-2d-arrays-using-pointers-with-boundary-conditions/20495563#20495563?newreg=0be47de8162e4020be2dfe13096f479d)

Here, in "answers", is a code of boundary conditions in Ising Model.
This code generate a matrix with all spins up:

```
for (i=0; i<Lattice_Size; i++)  {  
    for (j=0; j<Lattice_Size; j++) {
        *ptr++ = spin_up;   // initializing to parallel spins,      
                            // where spin_up is an integer number
                            // taking value = +1.
    }
}
```

My question is: *How one can set up a random configuration (matrix) with random distribution of spin_up / spin_down spins?*

I thought it might be done with the help of function `random(...)`, but I figured out that I don't understand well how it works :(

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function `rand` modulo 2:

```
srand(time(NULL)) ; // Initialize the rand see

for (i=0; i < Lattice_Size; i++)  {  
    for (j=0; j < Lattice_Size; j++) {
        *ptr++ = 1 - 2 * (rand() % 2); // Return either 1 or - 1
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include `time.h` and `stdlib.h`.

1. `rand()` returns a number in the range between `0` and `RAND_MAX`
2. `rand() % 2` returns either `0` or `1`
3. `2 * (rand() % 2)` returns either `0` or `2`
4. `1 - 2 * (rand() % 2)` returns `-1` or `1`.

If you are not familiar with it, `%` is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Is it normal that this code now generate random but always the same matrix? Is it possible to generate new random matrix every time?

Comment: @llama If you get the same matrix each time, it probably means that you forgot to call `srand(time(NULL))`. You should call `srand(time(NULL))` once at the beginning of your program (and not every time you want a new matrix).